# Mongodriver c# 2.2.3 UpdateOneAsync Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.StringSerializer'

Tags: mongodb, updates, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm refactoring my webapp to use the last mongo driver c# feature as async methods.

The find async methods are working well for now but I have an issue with UpdateOneAsync .

Here is my method in DAL :

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateOne<T>(FilterDefinition<T> filterDefinition, UpdateDefinition<T> updateDefinition)
{
    var coll = GetCollection<T>();
    var result = await coll.UpdateOneAsync(filterDefinition, updateDefinition);
    return result.ModifiedCount > 0;
}
```

And it's called from another class with this :

```
public virtual async Task<bool> UpdateField<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> findExpression, Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> fieldExpression, dynamic value)
{
    try
    {
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Where(findExpression);
        UpdateDefinition<T> updateFilter = Builders<T>.Update.Set(fieldExpression, value);

        var updateResult = await MongoClientWrapper.UpdateOne(filter, updateFilter);
        return updateResult;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          _logMongoRepo.ErrorFormat("(MongoRepo) Error on UpdateField : {0}", ex);
          return false;
     }
}
```

The error returned by UpdateOneAsync is :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.StringSerializer' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer`1[System.Object]
```

When I try to use UpdateOneAsync with my object Type, it's ok.

I really don't know where the error could come from :/